# Find second div with same class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Trying to find second div with same class on a page. I only retrieve the first one when fetching the data and cannot figure out how to get the second or third etc..

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument data = web.Load(URL);
var res = data.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='col-sm-5']");
```

Also I'm using two slash signs in the start, I don't know why but it worked. I've seen numerous of different solutions `("/", "./" "//" ".//").` Could someone explain the difference please?

Thanks in advance,
xolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
var res = data.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='col-sm-5']");
```

This is the difference between single and double slash:

`/`

1. start selection from the document node
2. allows you to create 'absolute' path expressions
3. e.g. “/html/body/p” matches all the paragraph elements

`//`

1. start selection matching anywhere in the docume
2. allows you to create 'relative' path expressions
3. e.g. “//p” matches all the paragraph elements

Comment: Thanks, but now that I've selected all divs with that class, how do select ONLY the second one like I've done with tables like `var res = data.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[2]");` I cant seem to figure out the syntax for it.. like `var res = data.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='col-sm-5'][X]");`??

Comment: SelectNodes returns a collection of nodes 'HtmlNodeCollection'. This is res in your case. So to access the second node, you can simply access it as res[1]. 1 because the first element is addressed as res[0] ;)